# Kubernetes: Can I replicate a volume to have a local persistentStorage in any node the Pod lanches?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a pod that needs to read from its persistentStorage.
I want to speed it up by having the persistentStorage being local to the pod. (This means I want to co-locate the storage and the pod to the same node.)

I could achieve this by e.g. creating [a local persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/) and forcing the pod and any of its replicas to always start on that node. ([by setting `nodeAffinity`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/))

My problem has to do with all the caveats described better than I could in [my first link](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/#limitations-of-ga).

The pod's storage would be used essentially to only read data, so a natural solution would be to have the storage replicated in every node, then have the pod use the local replica. The replicas would in theory be updated at a significant, but since there will be essentially no write operations, that cost would be negligent.

My question is how this can be implemented.

Also, apologies if the tags are not 100% correct, I am not sure I know which tags are appropriate here, feel free to point me to the right direction / fix my tags...

Comment: A few questions:   What's the size of the data?  Is the data really the same across all nodes?

Comment: size is too large to fit in memory, the data is the same: this is basically a read-only service that will answer to small queries about them